# recursive grep: exclude specific directories

Tags: linux, command-line, grep

I use recursive grep a lot to find source files with specific content.

```
grep -Rni "myfunc" .
```

On large codebases, this can get slow, so I use --incldue to restrict/whitelist extensions.

```
grep -Rni --include=*.java "myfunc" .
```

However, it would be more efficient to exclude (prune) whole subdirectories, I'm thinking:

```
grep -Rni --exclude=/.svn/ "myfunc" .
```

But the --exclude only supports file patterns like *.java above.
How can I exclude directories?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might look into [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/).

I've just started using it but it seems well-suited for this.

Comment: ack looks pretty good. nice that it intuitively excludes unwanted files. the --nogroup option gives a similar output to grep -Rni

Comment: Ack is a bit slow. You can try The Silver Searcher (Ag) or ripgrep (rg).

Answer (score 70):

```
grep -r --exclude-dir=dev --exclude-dir=sys --exclude-dir=proc PATTERN data
```

Source: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799246/grep-excluding-a-specific-folder-using

Comment: Note that this recursively excludes. `./dev` will be excluded ALONG WITH `./foo/bar/dev`. Use `--exclude-dir=./dev` to only apply to the first case.

Comment: You can also shorten this a bit by globbing:

```bash
grep -r --exclude-dir={dev,sys,proc} PATTERN data
```
The only problem with globbing is that I cannot get it to work in my bash. In that case I have to keep them separate.

Comment: Also noted that {} only works if you put more than 1 entries, that means --exclude-dir={home,.svn} is works but --exclude-dir={.svn} will not works. It waste my time to figure out why {} doesn't work because i test with 1 entry in the first place.

Comment: If you use `{}` with a single entry you probably need a unary comma to make it an array (not sure how Bash handles that). Instead of doing that I ended up making an alias in my .bash_aliases that loops over a list of folders I typically always want to exclude, eg .git, .svn, .hg, .cache, and then I add them via a loop with `--exclude-dir $dir` and then expand that array into the grep alias.

Answer (score 6):

you can use find instead:

```
find . -not -path "*/.svn*" -not -type d -exec grep -ni "myfunc" {} \; -print
```

OK, so that's a little backwards, you get the grep results first and **then** the path. Maybe someoe else has a better answer?

Comment: ok, i like that a lot. of course find is a lot more flexible.

the only difference between the output is that "grep -Rni" will print the file name for each match, whereas "find -exec grep" will print the filename on one line and then one line for each match (with line number and line content).

using "grep -Hni" forces the filename to be displayed on each line

Comment: Thank you for providing the only answer that worked for systems which are this crusty, without grep --exclude-dir, but still gotta be worked on

Answer (score 2):

Here's a full example from a script in one of my projects that might help, I call this file "all_source" (marked as executable) and put it in my project's root dir then call it like `grep myfunc $(./all_source)` the sort at the end of the script is totally optional.

```
#!/bin/bash

find . \
    -type d \( \
            -wholename './lib' -o \
            -wholename './vc6' -o \
            -name 'gen' -o \
            -name '.svn' \
            \) -prune -o \
    -type f \( \
            -name '*.h' -o \
            -name '*.cpp' -o \
            -name '*.c' -o \
            -name '*.lua' -o \
            -name '*.*awk' \) -print \
    | sort
```

This script returns all the file names in the project that match `*.h, *.cpp, *.c, *.lua, *.*awk`, but doesn't search in all folders named .svn and gen folders as well as skipping the folders for `./lib` and `./vc6` (but only the ones right off the project root). So when you do `grep myfunc $(./all_source)` it only greps in those files. You'll need to call this from the root dir of the project as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the -prune option to find:

```
 find . -path "*/.svn*" -prune -o -not -type d -exec grep -ni "myfunc" {} \; -print
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this:

```
grep -R  "myfunc" . | grep -v path_to_exclude/
```

Eg: If you don't want to search the content in log files just do the following:

```
grep -R "myfunc" . | grep -v log/
```